# Dummy Variable Regression in Python

Tags: python, dummy-variable

I would like to run create a dummy variable regression in Python. So, I have a list of rates from 2000 to 2020 and I want to estimate the non-crisis (NC) and crisis (C) period alphas and betas from the following model incorporating dummy variables with respect to alphas and the coefficients of the risk factors:

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKd40.png)

where Dnc,t is a dummy variable that takes a value of 1 for non-crisis periods and 0
otherwise and Dc,t is a dummy variable that takes a value of 1 for crisis periods and 0
otherwise. Now, I would like to run this regression in python.

Comment: And what have you done so far?  Do you have your data in a CSV, or in a Numpy array, or in a DataFrame?  What APIs do you think will work for this?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes I have my data in a CSV file. I'm using 
`import pandas as pd`
`import statsmodels.formula.api as smf`
`from statsmodels.iolib.summary2 import summary_col`

Then I import my df 
`df = pd.read_excel("MODEL.xlsx")` and I run my regression 
`model = smf.ols("y ~ Default + Market", data= df).fit(cov_type='HAC',cov_kwds={'maxlags':1})`
`dfoutput = summary_col([model1, model2, model3] ,stars=True, float_format='%0.6f')`
`print(dfoutput)`

However, as I said, I would incorporate a dummy variable to run a regression for Non-Crisis period and for Crisis period

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're looking for Logistic Regression and you already have your X and Y variables in Pandas dataframes

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X, y = Your_Predictor_Variables, Your_Target_Variable
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X, y)

print(clf.coef_, clf.intercept_)
```